jax bottom up processing non-perfect tree of objects
I have non-perfect, non-complete tree, which I would like to process bottom-up. I.e. level-t out put some values, which will be used in computations for level-(t+1), but level t+1 includes some fixed values also. Computations involve static shaped, but different size arrays.
I know how to process each level. Also for whole computations I know how to pre-compute all indexes that I will need during computations. However, I don't understand how to organise writing values from output level to next level in jax. This operations are local, hence I don't want to re-create the whole list each time. If outputs could be stored in single array instead of list, I would use in-place overwriting, so I can not.
I will discuss next in more details what is going on. I will use just integer numbers summation in order to emphasise only structure of computations, so I am interested in general non-commutative operations with different shaped tensors. Hence, some simplifications will not work.
Just python
def bin_(a, b):
    return a + b

def process_level(do, pairs):
    return [do(*pair) for pair in pairs]

def write_level_(what_write, where_write, seq):
    for k, v in zip(where_write, what_write):
        seq[k] = v

a, b, c, d, e, f = tuple(range(6))
seq = [None, None, e, None, f, None, a, b, c, d]

level_idx = [[6,7,8,9],[2,3,4,5],[0,1]]
level_p_idx = [[3,5],[0,1]]

for l, p in zip(level_idx, level_p_idx):
    pairs = zip(l[::2],l[1::2])
    l_out = process_level(bin_, pairs)
    write_level_(l_out, p, seq)

So, write_level_ change things in place, hence is not acceptable. However, I can not figure out what to do. One can note, that problem is similar to jax.lax.scan. This is true, but not quite: scan assumes perfect tree. Any suggestions appreciated. I guess I just don't know something basic about jax how to modify things, so I can not figure out by myself.

With slight modifications (making seq and array, changing in-place list updates to in-place array updates, and returning updated arrays) you can make this code compatible with jax.jit. For example:
import jax

def bin_(a, b):
    return a + b

def process_level(do, pairs):
    return [do(*pair) for pair in pairs]

def write_level_(what_write, where_write, seq):
    for k, v in zip(where_write, what_write):
        seq = seq.at[k].set(v)
    return seq

a, b, c, d, e, f = tuple(range(6))
seq = jax.numpy.array([-1, -1, e, -1, f, -1, a, b, c, d])

level_idx = [[6,7,8,9],[2,3,4,5],[0,1]]
level_p_idx = [[3,5],[0,1]]

@jax.jit
def f(seq, level_idx, level_p_idx):
    for l, p in zip(level_idx, level_p_idx):
        pairs = zip(l[::2],l[1::2])
        l_out = process_level(bin_, pairs)
        seq = write_level_(l_out, p, seq)
    return seq

seq = f(seq, level_idx, level_p_idx)
print(seq)
# [ 5  9  4 13  5 17  0  1  2  3]

With a bit more work you make things more efficient: i.e. change some lists into arrays and avoid some host-side iteration. For example, the write_level_ function could look something like this:
def write_level_(what_write, where_write, seq):
    where_write = jax.numpy.asarray(where_write)
    what_write = jax.numpy.asarray(what_write)
    return seq.at[where_write].set(what_write)

If where_write and what_write were arrays from the beginning, it would be even more efficient.
Beyond those kinds of optimizations, I think this is the best you can do with a general tree structure; if the nodes are identical in terms of number and shapes of children, you could replace the for loop with something like lax.scan, but depending on your ultimate goals that may or may not be possible or desirable.

Thanks for answer! Problem is that seq is list of arrays of different shapes. Hence, I can not use jax.numpy.array and .at[k].set, from my understanding.

OK - I’m just answering the question as you asked it. Best of luck with whatever code you’re actually running!

Sorry, I thought "If outputs could be stored in single array instead of list, I would use in-place overwriting, so I can not." means this. Anyway thanks for your always prompt and thoughtful replies!
